# Нужна ли в предложении запятая?

Tags: запятые

Он взял его за руку и стал уводить в сторону чуть дальше гостиной

Нужна ли запятая после слов "в сторону"?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна: *Он взял его за руку / и стал уводить в стОрону, // **чуть дальше гостИной**.*

**Пояснение**

Решение здесь практически **однозначное**. Обстоятельства неоднородные, но отношения между ними **уточняющие.** Это связано **со структурой** обстоятельственного оборота "в сторону чуть дальше гостиной:" его сложно прочитать без паузы, в одну фонетическую фразу.

**Для сравнения:** Он взял его зА руку / и стал уводить в сторону от гостИной. Это простое предложение, запятой нет.

**Примечание.** В предложениях обозначены **паузы и тонические ударения,** позволяющие уточнить произношение и выбрать знаки препинания.

Answer (score 0):

Если это одна фраза, то вряд ли нужна: он взял и стал.

А вот если уточнение, то:

[Он устроился на шахту, на неполный рабочий день – после уроков (Баруздин).](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724v#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%82%D1%83%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20(%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD).)

То есть:

Он взял его за руку и стал уводить, в сторону - чуть дальше гостиной).

Так как И - то *стал уводить тоже за руку*, но в сторону.

Есть *за руку*, *в сторону* и *чуть дальше гостиной*, относящееся только к *в сторону*.

*В сторону* относится не к *за руку*, а *в сторону от гостиной*. Ну *в сторону* уже к *взял* не относится. А вот *за руку* относится и к взял, и к стал уводить.

Наверное так!

Comment: Спасибо, только я не знаю, нужна ли запятая после слов "в сторону", не является ли уточнением "чуть дальше гостиной"?

Comment: Очень непонятно. Сначала пишете "если это вся фраза", потом то же самое, но уже с запятыми... А где продолжение с подчинённым предложением?

Comment: @Marusya как я понимаю, что, если ставите запятую после *в сторону*, то тогда появляется вопрос о постановке запятой перед *и*. Но постановка запятой *чуть дальше гостиной* - это дело вкусовщины и интонации.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец подчиненное выдумывать было лень)

Comment: Так чем "если бы было вот так" отличается от первого? // В любом случае первая запятая не нужна.

Comment: То есть "в сторону "чуть дальше гостиной" мы условно можем заменить на "в сторону "коридора"?..

Comment: @Marusya Я всё переделал)

Comment: Повеселили! :)))

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец ну последний вариант же - огонь!)

Comment: Ну я и говорю! 

Answer (score 0):

**ПРИНЦИП ОТСУТСТВИЯ ОТЧЁТЛИВЫХ ПРАВИЛ**

На мой взгляд, эту ситуацию нужно решать с помощью **принципа отсутствия отчётливых правил**. Он заключается в следующем: Если мы не имеем каких-то отчётливых инструкций по каким-то синтаксическим ситуациям, то мы можем просто написать их сами, но так, чтобы они не противоречили отчётливым официальным пунктам, в таком случае никто не сможет сказать, что мы ошиблись, если мы будем писать по таким инструкциям. Пунктуация не должна быть занозой в заднице, никому не нужны какие-то неопределённости, сложности, колебания и т. д.

**ПРОБЛЕМА**

Принято считать, что в такой ситуации в зависимости от пауз может быть двоякая пунктуация, например, в таком предложении: ‟3автра в шесть часов вечера состоится заседание кафедры” и ‟3автра, в шесть часов вечера, состоится заседание кафедры”. Имеется в виду, что в первом предложении идёт два обстоятельства места, а во втором предложении ‟в шесть часов вечера” произносится с такой интонацией отступления, как обособляемое слово в следующем предложении: ‟Отца, пьяницу, кормила с малых лет, и сама себя”. Но трудность заключается в том, что в первом варианте (с рядом однородных обстоятельств времени) также есть две паузы по краям второго обстоятельства места – первая, как между обычными однородными без союза, вторая, как после обстоятельства времени, находящегося в начале предложениях. Эта ситуация, что в обоих случаях (при отступлении и при ряде обстоятельств) есть две паузы по краям, создаёт трудности. Понятно, почему в такой ситуации возникли сложности без отчётливого предписания.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Решением этой ситуации будет простое предписание, что **запятые в такой ситуации не ставятся**. Поскольку пунктуация в таких ситуациях хаотична, то вы можете просто **не ставить запятые никогда** и никто не сможет сказать, что вы тут ошиблись.

Но тут есть проблема: нельзя отменить всякие вставки, присоединения, пояснения, которые могут быть в любом предложении. И вот как эта проблема разрешается.

**УТОЧНЕНИЕ? НЕ, НЕ СЛЫШАЛ.**

Раз уж эта запятая убирается, то я вообще выпилил бы термин ‟уточнение”, а какие-то остаточные ситуации запихнул бы в термин ‟пояснение”. Кто-то считает обособленное слово в таком предложении уточнением: ‟Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил”, но если посмотреть на определение пояснения в справочнике Розенталя, то это слово уже в пояснении:

> ...пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.

И если посмотреть на примеры в справочнике Розенталя, то там вовсе не разъяснения в большинстве ситуаций.

То есть считать пояснение не разъяснением чего-то, что может быть непонятно, с помощью обозначения другим словом или словами в отступлении, а просто любым отступлением, где что-то обозначается другим словом или словами.

Кстати, я считаю, что большой ошибкой в строительстве терминологии является добавление в пояснение таких ситуаций (в справочнике Розенталя):

> В жизни есть только одно несомненное счастье — жить для других (Л. Т.)
> Семёна была своя золотая и несбывшаяся мечта — стать столяром (Пауст.).
> Он обладает особой способностью — всё делать вовремя.

Я считаю, что здесь отношения с раскрываемым и раскрывающим (не с интонацией отступления, а с предупредительной интонацией на конце предложения), как в сочетаниях дерево осина, бригадир Зырянский, книга ‟Война и Мир”. Вот с таким выстраиванием терминологии (добавлять это в пояснение) нужно спорить, а не о том, является ли порядковое числительное прилагательным.

**ЧТО ТАМ БУДЕТ ПРИ ОБОСОБЛЕНИИ ЗАПЯТЫМИ**

В таких ситуациях нужно не обособлять. Если всегда не обособлять, то никто не уличит вас в ошибке. Но если обособить, то это будет присоединение. То есть когда человек не задумывал говорить второе обстоятельство, но решает дополнить предложение этим присоединением по ходу произнесения. Но тут нужно быть аккуратным, потому что не ставить запятые можно в любом предложении, но ставить запятые, указывающие на присоединение, можно не всегда. Например, взгляните на предложения:

> Он живёт в Москве, в общежитии. (Человек мог задумать такое предложение без сочетания ‟в общежитии”.)
> Он хотел работать на заводе, в лаборатории. (Маловероятно, что кто-то задумал бы такое предложение без ‟в лаборатории”, потому что кто хочет работать просто на заводе.)

**КОРОТКАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ОТВЕТА**

Просто можете всегда не ставить запятые в таких случаях, потому что так как никто не имеет отчётливых инструкций, то никто не сможет уличить вас в ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу писать комментарии, поэтому отвечу здесь на ответ пользователя Sharon.

Во-первых, две черты означают границу фразы, чего там, где вы поставили эти две черты, быть не может. Граница фразы – это такая большая пауза, которая в основном между предложениями (не предложениями внутри составного). Я могу привести множество примеров из пособия, если хотите, чтобы вы поняли, о каких паузах идёт речь

Вы расставили тонические ударения, а потом сказали, что из этого как-то следует то, что там нет запятой, но там нет запятой не из-за тонических ударения (я, конечно, не знаю, что это), а из-за двух однородных, соединённых одиночным союзом.

А не могли бы вы пояснить, что такое фонетическая фраза. Я нашёл только это определение:

> Фонетическая фраза — отрезок речи, представляющий собой интонационно-смысловое единство, выделенное с обеих сторон паузами.

Я вообще ничего не понимаю в этом определении.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147008/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.